# Move form button to left on Ext.form.panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-grid, extjs-form

I have basic Ext.form.panel component in my application. I used the buttons:[{list of buttons}] property to add reset and submit buttons for the form.

Everything looks well and works well except the buttons are always positioned towards the right side of the form.

I have grid which is on right of the form and when I resize the browser the grid covers the buttons so they are not visible. (form and grid are postioned using column layout)

I would like to move form buttons to the left of the form.

Is there some property to do this?

I tried align:"left" but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

buttonAlign: 'left' should work, http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-cfg-buttonAlign